# Export R output to Excel

Tags: r, excel

I like using R for statistical analysis but find it difficult to compare output of different models.

Is there any way, we can **export output to excel** to make it more readable (using some formatting like scientific to number notation, conditional formatting etc)?

As suggested by @42 [How to Copy Summary() output from R to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400492/how-to-copy-summary-output-from-r-to-excel), I tried capture.output() but it doesn't work properly. I've searched a lot, couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Have you looked into the SO archive? E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618556/export-data-frames-to-excel-via-xlsx-with-conditional-formatting

Comment: have a look at `broom` package for tidying model objects

Comment: Do you mean the result of `print.summary` for some particular class of object.  The issue is that the print.summary methods for different classes of object are so different that I doubt there will be a single method that will work for everything.  You could try experimenting with something like `xtable` or `stargazer` that can produce html summary tables that could be imported into excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long back, I had asked this question as I was curious about how to get publication-ready results & tables from the output of different models in R.

Later, I found many beautiful ways to do so and even wrote a [LinkedIn post](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/drnishaarora_r-learnersworld-data-activity-6888304387421163520-OPQ-?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop) about the same.
Today, someone asked me the same question & It clicked to my mind that I should answer this question on SO too as many R users might not be knowing.

#SPSS users usually look for table format that can be pasted in excel/word or pdf.

Here are the available options :

1. broom package

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html

The broom package takes the messy output of built-in functions in R, such as lm, nls, or t.test, and turns them into tidy tibbles.

broom::tidy() _ It constructs a tibble that summarizes the model’s statistical findings. This includes coefficients and p-values for each term in a regression, per-cluster information in clustering applications, or per-test information for multtest functions
broom::augment() _ add columns to the original data that was modeled. This includes predictions, residuals, and cluster assignments
broom::glance() _ It constructs a concise one-row summary of the model. This typically contains values such as R^2, adjusted R^2, and residual standard error that are computed once for the entire model.

2. gt summary package
   It provides  Presentation-Ready Data Summary and Analytic Result Tables

Both 1 & 2 are my favorite

3. sjPlot package
   https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/no-need-for-spss-beautiful-output-in-r-rstats/
4. expss package for tables with labels
   https://gdemin.github.io/expss/
5. r2spss pacakge
   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/r2spss/vignettes/r2spss-intro.pdf

Some screenshots might be helpful.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using the package `XLConnect` you can write R output to Excel files.

Here's an example, where I write a model and send the summary to excel:

```
library(XLConnect)
dat <- data.frame(rsp = rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
                  pred1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
                  pred2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1))
model <- lm(rsp ~ pred1 + pred2, data = dat)
writeWorksheetToFile("model1.xlsx", 
                 data = summary(dat), 
                 sheet = "summary", 
                 header = TRUE,
                 clearSheets = TRUE)
```

Comment: When **library(XLConnect)** produces an error: "No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry" on 64bit R, you need to install 64bit version of Java.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to export the output of `summary` function, try this

```
write.csv(summary(data_frame),"output.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem a while ago and started using the package `stargazer`. It doesn't export output to Excel, but makes nice HTML, Latex and ASCII tables which can be copy pasted to Excel. In my opinion the strength of the package is that it allows to quickly create a table which compares different models.

More info: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf

Answer (score 2):

As @David_B said, `stargazer` package is really nice for simple tables and can output to txt,html.

If you want to output your dataframe as an Excel file, then have a look at the `xlsx` package.

Be aware that `xlsx` doesn't work with a `dplyr tbl_df` and you will need to define it as a dataframe e.g.

```
write.xlsx (x = as.data.frame(df), file = "foo.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose a simple solution via the clipboard. Function tabout sends the normal output to the console plus a tab-delimited version thereof to the clipboard. Then, you can directly paste e.g. into excel.

```
tabout <- function(output){
  print(output)
  capture.output(output, file = "clipboard", append = FALSE, 
    type = "output", split = FALSE)
  lines <- readClipboard()
  for(i in 1 : 5) {lines <- gsub("  ", " ", lines, fixed=TRUE)}
  lines <- gsub(" ", "\t", lines, fixed=TRUE)
  writeClipboard(lines)
}

myanova <- Anova(mymodel, type="III")
tabout(myanova)
```

While this is mocog = most ordinary code of the galaxy ;^), it does the main job of placing numbers in columns. A slightly more elaborate version below uses a set of phrases that include blanks, but should be kept in one piece in the output (i.e should not be split by inserting tab's).

```
glmphrases <- c(
  "Sum Sq", "F value", "Std. Error", "t value", "test statistic", 
  "test stat", "approx F", "num Df", "den Df", "p adj",
  " = ", " ~ ", " : ", " on ", " and ", "Signif. codes: 0", 
  "'***' 0.001", "'**' 0.01", "'*' 0.05", "'.' 0.1", "' ' 1"
)

tabout <- function(output, phrases = glmphrases){
# send "output" to the console and a copy to the clipboard
print(output)
capture.output(output, file = "clipboard", append = FALSE, 
  type = "output", split = FALSE)
lines <- readClipboard()
# collapse repeated blanks and replace with tabs
for(i in 1 : 5) {lines <- gsub("  ", " ", lines, fixed=TRUE)}
lines <- gsub(" ", "\t", lines, fixed=TRUE)
# retain each phrase in one piece and write back to clipboard
phrases.tab <- gsub(" ", "\t", phrases, fixed=TRUE)
for(i in 1 : length(phrases)){
  lines <- gsub(phrases.tab[i], phrases[i],  lines, fixed=TRUE)
  }
writeClipboard(lines)
}

myanova <- Anova(mymodel, type="III")
tabout(myanova)
```

Hope this is useful, best wishes

Kleks

Answer (score 0):

You can write data to a .csv file using `write.csv()` or `write.csv2()`. CSV documents can be opened in Excel and saved as .xls if you want to edit the formatting etc.

And this is not a solution, but run `options(scipen=100)`. That configures R not to use scientific notation, so when you view a dataframe you see the numeric values in regular decimal form.

Comment: How can I use options(scipen=100) for summary of linear model? Please provide sample code.

Comment: You just execute that line, it's very simple. If you execute the command, all output generated after that will use those display settings. You can set it back to default by specifying a different integer setting instead of the 100.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I couldn't really understand [significance of '100'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10) and 'digits' as suggested by Dirk. [The description here is also not clear to me](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html). Would you please help?

Comment: Also, how to get default setting (output in scientific notation) again?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** There is actually a way to copy-paste tabular data (say "data.frame" class objects) to Excel, though Windows-only. Try this:

```
write.table(your_object, "clipboard", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)
```

Replace `your_object` with a name of an actual data frame, but other arguments should stay as they are, including `"clipboard"`.

Execution of the command will return nothing, but now you can switch to Excel and paste your table.

If you don’t need column names, add `col.names = FALSE`. For comma as a decimal separator, add `dec = “,”`.

**2.** Now, since you need to copy-paste some model output, you should preliminarily convert it into something table-like. The package `broom` is rather popular in this regard and was already suggested here, so I just bring it up once again.

Answer (score -1):

I used the "readxl" package. It worked wonderfully for exporting data to excel.

```
install.packages("readxl")
library(readxl)
input <- read_excel("data/mydata.xlsx")
```

You can chose to export data into SAS, database or online using options provided here: https://www.blue-granite.com/blog/importing-and-exporting-getting-data-into-and-out-of-r

Comment: This *reads* an excel file, doesn't *write* to it